# Using GageWatershed Function in TauDEM?

Tags: hydrology, watershed, taudem

I have a D8 flow direction raster made from with TauDEM's D8FlowDir method and a point vector with an attribute 'id' for each.  For some reason when I use these two as input in the GageWatershed method I get a single large watershed instead of a watershed for each point.  I checked several pages to make sure my point vector has the right attribute name.  Could someone please advise.

I have the D8 raster, point vector, and bad result watershed raster located at the following:

ftp://ftpext.usgs.gov/pub/er/va/reston/gpetrochenkov/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the TauDEM release 5.3.7 (which is the latest release).  It occurs with a huge number of points (1102144 in this case) in the outlet shapefile and is most likely due to variable type errors and numeric overflows.  There have been code improvements that address these and the problem does not occur in develop branch code in github http://github.com/dtarb/taudem, so will be resolved at the next release.  I did not track down the exact problem, but verified that the problem was reproducible with the provided data version 5.3.7 but is resolved in current develop code.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this David!  It turns out that the point shape file had to both be a point geometry without the z dimension and have a datatype of int32 for id attribute instead of int64.  Afterwards it worked just fine.